# system.version more than 3 decimal points c#

Tags: c#, linq, system.version

I am currently receiving the following error - 
"Version string portion was too short or too long"

When using this statement -

```
records = records.OrderBy(r => new Version(r.RefNo)).ToList();
```

To order a list of string's called RefNo. It fails on 25.1.2.1.2 so i assume it is because it has four decimal points? as it works ok with 3....

Is the max four deciaml points for system.version?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6 `Is the max four deciaml points for system.version?` Yes.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hf9t2e(v=vs.110).aspx - have a look at remarks `The version parameter can contain only the components major, minor, build, and revision, in that order, and all separated by periods.`

Comment: Those aren't decimal points. A decimal point is a `.` character (typically called "full stop" or "period") placed in a set of digits to separate the integral portion of a number from the fractional portion. (In some other contexts, the decimal point may be the comma, `,`). Notably, it *does not make sense* for any number to contain more than a single decimal point.

Comment: And the reason I try to make people get very clear on this is to make people realise that version `3.20` is different to version `3.2`, and is a later version than `3.9`. It's people who act as if it *is* a decimal separator (and somehow create a rule where you ignore the subsequent `.`s) who end up not understanding version numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hf9t2e(v=vs.110).aspx) can only have 4 parts:

> major, minor, build, and revision, in that order, and all separated by
>   periods.

That's why your approach fails. You could create an extension-method which handles this case, f.e.:

```
public static Version TryParseVersion(this string versionString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(versionString))
        return null;

    String[] tokens = versionString.Split('.');
    if (tokens.Length < 2 || !tokens.All(t => t.All(char.IsDigit)))
        return null;

    if (tokens.Length > 4)
    {
        int maxVersionLength = tokens.Skip(4).Max(t => t.Length);
        string normalizedRest = string.Concat(tokens.Skip(4).Select(t => t.PadLeft(maxVersionLength, '0')));
        tokens[3] = $"{tokens[3].PadLeft(maxVersionLength, '0')}{normalizedRest}";
        Array.Resize(ref tokens, 4);
    }

    versionString = string.Join(".", tokens);
    bool valid = Version.TryParse(versionString, out Version v);
    return valid ? v : null;
}
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
records = records
   .OrderBy(r => r.RefNo.TryParseVersion())
   .ToList();
```

With your sample this new version string will be parsed(successfully): `25.1.2.12`

Comment: Tim, this is great thanks for the tip. I will take a look at creating an extension method.

Comment: @bsod_: in the last code snippet  was a bug, it's: `.OrderBy(r => r.RefNo.TryParseVersion())`

Answer (score 1):

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y0hf9t2e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Costructor `public Version(string version)`

> A string containing the major, minor, build, and revision numbers,
>   where each number is delimited with a period character ('.').

Makes a total of 4 numbers.

Means the string is limited to 4 numbers, 5 lead to an error.

Also the costructors with `int`'s as parameters only support 1 to 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply but here is the finished extension method i used with a couple of alterations -

```
public static Version ParseRefNo(this string refNoString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(refNoString))
                return null;

            String[] tokens = refNoString.Split('.');
            if (tokens.Length < 2 || !tokens.All(t => t.All(char.IsDigit)))
                return null;

            if (tokens.Length > 4)
            {
                int maxVersionLength = tokens.Skip(4).Max(t => t.Length);
                string normalizedRest = string.Concat(tokens.Skip(4).Select(t => t.PadLeft(maxVersionLength, '0')));
                tokens[3] = $"{tokens[3].PadLeft(maxVersionLength, '0')}{normalizedRest}";
                Array.Resize(ref tokens, 4);
            }

            refNoString = string.Join(".", tokens);
            Version v = null;
            bool valid = Version.TryParse(refNoString, out v);
            return valid ? v : null;
        }
```